# Ubuntu utilities disappeared but still show up in "Show Applications"

Tags: software-installation, software-center, uninstall, software-uninstall

Not sure, what the problem is.

I have Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome.

Today some of my apps, installed with GUI Ubuntu Software, stopped launching (for example: Thunderbird, Chromium, Discord). It's weird, I still have icons in "Show Applications", but when I click they are like being launched for few seconds and then die.

I was trying to remove and reinstall the broken apps, but APT manager says there are no such applications. I installed Thunderbird one more time, with command line, and it works, but I now have two almost identical icons in Show App-s being anxious about such ugliness and probably some mess under the hood (they could just disappear, right?).

More to say, when I click "Show details" on such disappeared app icon, Ubuntu Software says "No application found".

I searched for a while but couldn't find any issues like this, nor relevant solutions.

I update my system regularly. My assumption is that it's the Ubuntu Sofware Center's fault. I noticed it's homepage was updated, seems like Canonical rebuilt their app center recently.

Has anyone got such problems? How to fix them?

I also need to mention that yesterday, before the issue occurred, I mounted sftp filesystem from my other laptop with SSH server in Nautilus. Could it break apps?

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled `gnome-software`, so it could finally detect the disappeared packages.

To do it, proceed in your terminal:

```
sudo apt --purge remove gnome-software
```

Then:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install gnome-software
```

Jeez, I'll never ever install utilities with GUI.